# How to write contents of help to a file from within R?

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to write the contents of a help file in R to a file from within R.
The following works from the command-line:

- `R --slave -e 'library(MASS); help(survey)' > survey.txt`

  - This command writes the help file for the survey data file
  - `--slave` hides both the initial prompt and commands entered from the
    resulting output
  - `-e '...'` sends the command to R
  - `> survey.txt` writes the output of R to the file `survey.txt`

However, this does not seem to work:

```
library(MASS)
sink("survey.txt")
help(survey)
sink()
```

- How can I save the contents of a help file to a file from within R?

Comment: You should be able to do better than this. R itself is now processing the Rd markup, so there **must** be parsers and converters in `tools` and other base R packages.

Comment: Related to [R help page as object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918753/r-help-page-as-object).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like the two functions you would need are `tools:::Rd2txt` and `utils:::.getHelpFile`.  This prints the help file to the console, but you may need to fiddle with the arguments to get it to write to a file in the way you want.

For example:

```
hs <- help(survey)
tools:::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(as.character(hs)))
```

Since these functions aren't currently exported, I would not recommend you rely on them for any production code.  It would be better to use them as a guide to create your own stable implementation.

Answer (score 3):

While Joshua's instructions work perfectly, I stumbled upon another strategy for saving an R helpfile; So I thought I'd share it. It works on my computer (Ubuntu) where `less` is the R pager. It essentially just involves saving the file from within `less`.

- `help(survey)`
- Then follow [these instructions](http://0x657573.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/saving-less-buffer-to-a-file/) to save `less` buffer to file

  - i.e., type `g|$tee survey.txt`

    - `g` goes to the top of the less buffer if you aren't already there
    - `|` pipes text between the range starting at current mark
    - and ending at `$` which indicates the end of the buffer
    - to the shell command `tee` which allows standard out to be sent to a file