# In R, can I get the help text for a function into a variable?

Tags: r

I'd like to programmatically generate a list of functions with the titles from their help pages, something like this:

```
sd: Standard Deviation 
cov: Correlation, Variance and Covariance (Matrices)
anova: Anova Tables 
...
```

I tried storing the result of `help()` in a variable, but I can't figure out how to get the text. However I go about it, it runs LESS with the help text or shows it in the browser.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if you look at `dput(help(sd))`, it'll give you the path to where to find the `html` file used to generate the page

Comment: `readLines(system.file("INDEX", package = "stats"))`

Comment: This dupe target seems good also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918753/r-help-page-as-object

Comment: @josliber's answer is great, but in case somebody needs to get another section from the help of a function (like the description), here's a short gist I wrote to do it: https://gist.github.com/gooli/938d53f0289f2234e2f3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `help.search` could be of use. For instance, if I wanted everything in the `base` package:

```
x <- help.search("*", package="base")
entries <- data.frame(entry=x$matches$Entry, title=x$matches$Title)
entries[c(1, 100, 1000),]
#          entry                               title
# 1            +                Arithmetic Operators
# 100  c.POSIXlt                   Date-Time Classes
# 1000  encoding Functions to Manipulate Connections
```