# Extract information from 'See Also' part of R help for given function

Tags: r, documentation

For example `?rep` returns `R Help on 'rep'` window, in section `See Also` we have
`‘seq’, ‘sequence’, ‘replicate’`, for `rep()` function I would like to obtain vector `c("seq", "sequence", "replicate")`, I've tried to analyse `example()` function, which makes something similar for `Examples` section

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918753/r-help-page-as-object might help ...  or manually `hlp <- utils:::.getHelpFile(help(rep)) ;
unlist(hlp[sapply(hlp, function(i) attributes(i)$Rd_tag == "\\seealso")])`, gets close??