# Create bib_text citations in R?

Tags: r, citations

Using the help function in R sometimes includes a citation in what looks like APA formatting. For instance, the `closeness` function in `igraph` has.

```
?closeness
Freeman, L.C. (1979). Centrality in Social Networks I: Conceptual Clarification. Social Networks, 1, 215-239.
```

I'm writing in RMarkdown and would like to create a `Bibtext` style format for this citation using R (i.e., not pull it from another source). Is this possible?

For example, a function like:

```
cit <- some_function('Freeman, L.C. (1979). Centrality in Social Networks I: 
 Conceptual Clarification. Social Networks, 1, 215-239.')

cit 

@article{freeman1978conceptual,
  title={conceptual clarification.” Social Networks},
  author={Freeman, Linton C},
  journal={“Centrality in social networks},
  volume={1},
  number={3},
  pages={215--239},
  year={1978}
}
```

Comment: I don't thing it is possible. The references given in the documentation are simply string that can be freely formatted by the package authors. Therefore there is no way to parse the references consistently.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function around, [`getHTMLhelp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928894/6574038) that scrapes documentations.

With its help you can put the needed information into a vector.

```
vec <- getHTMLhelp(closeness, package="igraph")[102:103]
```

Because it's containing html tags you may want to clean it from them and get a single string.

```
string <- gsub("<[^>]*>","", paste(vec, collapse=""))
```

Then you can split this up like so:

```
rw <- t(strsplit(string, "\\. ")[[1]])
yr <- gsub("\\D", "", rw[2])
ref <- paste0(strsplit(tolower(rw[1]), ",")[[1]][1], yr,
              strsplit(tolower(rw[3]), " ")[[1]][1])
jrnl <- strsplit(rw[4], ", ")[[1]]
```

Now `cat` it.

```
cat(paste0("@article{", ref,"," ,
           "\n\ttitle={", rw[3], "},",
           "\n\tauthor={", rw[1], "},",
           "\n\tjournal={", jrnl[1], "},",
           "\n\tvolume={", jrnl[2], "},",
           "\n\tpages={", gsub("\\.", "", jrnl[3]), "},",
           "\n\tyear={", yr, "}",
           "\n}"
))
```

***Result***

```
@article{freeman1979centrality,
    title={Centrality in Social Networks I:Conceptual Clarification},
    author={Freeman, L.C},
    journal={Social Networks},
    volume={1},
    pages={215-239},
    year={1979}
}
```

Of course this is now specifically related to your example and needs to be generalized further.