# How to read meta data about R function?

Tags: r

Let say there is an R function "add" from the "R Packages" book

```
#' Add together two numbers
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Is it possible to get data about @param value in some way?

For example, to have function "get_function_meta_data('function_name')" that returns list of function parameters with their descriptions. For example, for function 'add' this function should return something like:

```
get_function_meta_data('add')
> 'param x' =  'A number'
> 'param y' = 'A number'
```

Thanks ahead for any ideas!

Comment: Either `formals`, which is only a partial answer, or else [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8918753/324364) is maybe a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! The "formals" return only names of arguments: "formals(add)" => "$x" and "$y". But how to get the description of these arguments "'A number'?

Comment: Andrii, unfortunately `formals` won't give you all of that additional information (it'll tell you `x=` but not `A number`). Those preceding `#'` comments are one of two things: (1) for `roxygen2` to convert into an R help file (`*.Rd`), accessible with `help("add")` or `?add`, assuming that this is in an R package; and even if 1 isn't true, (2) they're just structured comments for the function; unfortunately, they're not within the definition of the function, so even if you could retain comments within a function, these are not ... so they're only accessible in the source file itself.

Comment: You'll note that I specifically said in my comment that `formals` is only a partial answer, which suggests that I'm acknowledging that it will only give you the parameter names. The other question I linked to is the only other option I know of, which requires that you literally parse the entire help text.