# how can I extract text from R's help command?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R help page as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918753/r-help-page-as-object)

I can do

```
temp <- help('ls')
```

But I can't get a handle on this object. I don't think there's much meat in it except a call is there? `unclass`, `str`, `attributes` don't seem to lead anywhere.

I would like to, for example,

(1) Extract the text of the `Details` section of the help for `ls`; and

(2) Extract all the text into one big string.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is your question the same as [How to write contents of help to a file from within R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493843/how-to-write-contents-of-help-to-a-file-from-within-r)?

Comment: Check also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918753/r-help-page-as-object/8928894#8928894

Comment: Yes, these are basically the same question. I did not find them in my search before. Should I close/delete?

Comment: @XuWang: I wouldn't delete because there's some great content in the answers.  Close/merge would seem more appropriate.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich ah, ok. Thanks for your suggestion. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`help` itself doesn't return anything useful.  To get the help text, you can read the contents of the help database for a package, and parse that.

```
extract_help <- function(pkg, fn = NULL, to = c("txt", "html", "latex", "ex"))
{
  to <- match.arg(to)
  rdbfile <- file.path(find.package(pkg), "help", pkg)
  rdb <- tools:::fetchRdDB(rdbfile, key = fn)
  convertor <- switch(to, 
      txt   = tools::Rd2txt, 
      html  = tools::Rd2HTML, 
      latex = tools::Rd2latex, 
      ex    = tools::Rd2ex
  )
  f <- function(x) capture.output(convertor(x))
  if(is.null(fn)) lapply(rdb, f) else f(rdb)
}
```

`pkg` is a character string giving the name of a package
`fn` is a character string giving the name of a function within that package.  If it is left as `NULL`, then the help for all the functions in that package gets returned.
`to` converts the help file to txt, tml or whatever.

Example usage:

```
#Everything in utils
extract_help("utils")

#just one function
extract_help("utils", "browseURL")

#convert to html instead
extract_help("utils", "browseURL", "html")

#a non-base package 
extract_help("plyr")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

The `help()` function has an argument called `help_type`, which can take the following arguments: "text", "html", "postscript", "ps" and "pdf". Does running `help(ls, help_type = "text")` help solving your problem?

Comment: no actually that's the default. But thank you for your suggestion!