# How to extract names of functions from 'See Also' section of help files in R?

Tags: r, cran

How to extract names of functions from 'See Also' section of help files ?
For example :
from object=help(lm)
from "See Also" section :

```
 ‘summary.lm’ for summaries and ‘anova.lm’ for the ANOVA table;
 ‘aov’ for a different interface.

 The generic functions ‘coef’, ‘effects’, ‘residuals’, ‘fitted’,
 ‘vcov’.

 ‘predict.lm’ (via ‘predict’) for prediction, including confidence
 and prediction intervals; ‘confint’ for confidence intervals of
 _parameters_.
```

I would like to have a vector of functions names - "summary.lm","anova.lm","coef" ...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493843/how-to-write-contents-of-help-to-a-file-from-within-r

Comment: Perhaps you could use [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192589/how-can-i-extract-text-from-rs-help-command), which extracts the help file as a character string, and then `grep` for the lines between `See Also` and the next section title, matching on names surrounded in that funny tick.