# Shiny - Printing an R Help file

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to print an R help file in Shiny?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("help_file")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$help_file <- renderText(help(diamonds))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Previous answers about extracting help text might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192589/how-can-i-extract-text-from-rs-help-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I extract text from R's help command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192589/how-can-i-extract-text-from-rs-help-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by @semaphorism, you can use `extract_help` function from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192589/how-can-i-extract-text-from-rs-help-command):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("help_file")
)

extract_help <- function(pkg, fn = NULL, to = c("txt", "html", "latex", "ex"))
{
  to <- match.arg(to)
  rdbfile <- file.path(find.package(pkg), "help", pkg)
  rdb <- tools:::fetchRdDB(rdbfile, key = fn)
  convertor <- switch(to, 
                      txt   = tools::Rd2txt, 
                      html  = tools::Rd2HTML, 
                      latex = tools::Rd2latex, 
                      ex    = tools::Rd2ex
  )
  f <- function(x) capture.output(convertor(x))
  if(is.null(fn)) lapply(rdb, f) else f(rdb)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$help_file <- renderText(extract_help("ggplot2", "diamonds", to="html"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```