# Print R package function index to console

Tags: r

I want to print the documentation for an R package to the console. Doing

```
utils:::.getHelpFile(help("print"))
```

works just fine but when I try

```
utils:::.getHelpFile(help(package="MASS"))
```

I get an error stating:

```
Error in dirname(file) : a character vector argument expected
```

So my question is: how can I print the documentation for an R package (i.e `help(package="package_name")`) to the console? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking for the table of contents (index) of help files there.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven. Yes, the index of the package.

Comment: @RichardScriven it not basically the same thing because with `ls()` i) I need to load the package first and ii) I don't get a short description of what the function does.

Comment: Related: [How to write contents of help to a file from within R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7493843/271616)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`help(package = "MASS")` takes you to the *INDEX* file for the *MASS* package, opened in a browser window (depending on your settings).  To read that file into the console, we can use `system.file()` to get the file path, then `readLines()` to read it as a character vector.

```
## get the complete file path for the index file of the MASS package
f <- system.file("INDEX", package = "MASS")
## read it
readLines(f)
# [1] "Functions:"                                  
# [2] "========="
# [3] ""
# [4] "Null                    Null Spaces of Matrices"
# [5] "addterm                 Try All One-Term Additions to a Model"
# [6] "anova.negbin            Likelihood Ratio Tests for Negative Binomial GLMs"
# ...
# ...
```

Or we can wrap it in `cat()` to get a cleaner version

```
cat(readLines(f), sep = "\n")
# Functions:
# =========
#
# Null                    Null Spaces of Matrices
# addterm                 Try All One-Term Additions to a Model
# anova.negbin            Likelihood Ratio Tests for Negative Binomial GLMs
# ...
# ...
```

Alternatively, you could get the same result with

```
readLines(file.path(find.package("MASS"), "INDEX"))
```

Finally, if you're wondering about the links to the package description and news that appear at the top of the html browser, those can be obtained with

```
packageDescription("MASS")
news(package = "MASS")
```

Comment: `help(package="foo")` doesn't always open a browser window. It depends on your settings (see the `help_type` arg in `?help`). Also, there's no "index" file in packages. The file is "INDEX", so your code won't work on systems where file names are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich - I was wondering why `index` worked on my machine as well as `INDEX`.  Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

`utils:::.getHelpFile(help(package="MASS"))` doesn't work because `help(pacakge="MASS")` returns a `packageInfo` class object, not a `help_files_with_topic` class object (which is a full file path with some other attributes).

Here's the simplest thing I can come up with:

```
cat(paste(format(help(package="MASS", help_type="text")), collapse="\n"),"\n")
```

Basically, you `format` the output from `help(package="MASS")`. Then `paste` that result into a single character string, collapsed together by newlines. Then call `cat` on that result.